# UnboundLocalError at /memberships/payment ocal variable 'course' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, django, python-3.7

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView,View
from memberships.models import UserMembership
from .models import Course, Lesson

# Create your views here.
class CourseListView(ListView):
    model = Course

class CourseDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Course

class LessonDetailView(View):
    def get(self,request,course_slug,lesson_slug, *args,**kwargs):

        course_qs = Course.objects.filter(slug=course_slug)
        if course_qs.exists():
            course = course_qs.first()

        lesson_qs = course.lessons.filter(slug=lesson_slug)
        if lesson_qs.exists():
            lesson = lesson_qs.first()

        user_membership = UserMembership.objects.filter(user=request.user).first()
        user_membership_type = user_membership.membership.membership_type

        course_allowed_mem_types = course.allowed_memberships.all()

        context = {
            'object' : None
        }
        if  course_allowed_mem_types.filter(membership_type=user_membership_type).exists():
            context = {'object': lesson}
        return render(request, "courses/lesson_detail.html",context)
```

```
Internal Server Error: /memberships/payment
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\Envs\web\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\Envs\web\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\Envs\web\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\Envs\web\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\Envs\web\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\myproject\cpx\courses\views.py", line 20, in get
    lesson_qs = course.objects.filter(slug=lesson_slug)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'course' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: if course_qs doesn't exist course is not defined variable

Comment: course.lessons.filter(slug=lesson_slug) . there is no model name as course. actually the model name is Course so it should be Course.lessons.filter(slug=lesson_slug).

Comment: now gets a new error 'property' object has no attribute 'filter'

Answer (score 0):

- > ```
  > from django.conf import settings
  > from django.contrib import messages
  > from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
  > from django.shortcuts import render
  > from django.urls import reverse
  > from django.views.generic import ListView
  > from .models import Membership , UserMembership, Subscription
  > import stripe
  > # Create your views here.
  >
  > def get_user_membership(request):
  >    user_membership_qs = UserMembership.objects.filter(user = request.user)
  >    if user_membership_qs.exists():
  >        return user_membership_qs.first()
  >
  >    return None
  >
  > def get_user_subscription(request):
  >    user_subscription_qs =  Subscription.objects.filter(
  >        user_membership = get_user_membership(request))
  >    if user_subscription_qs.exists():
  >        user_subscription = user_subscription_qs.first()
  >        return user_subscription
  >    return None 
  >
  > def get_selected_membership(request):
  >    membership_type = request.session['selected_membership_type']   
  >    selected_membership_qs = Membership.objects.filter(
  >            membership_type = selected_membership_type)
  >    if selected_membership_qs.exists():
  >        return selected_membership_qs.first()
  >    return None 
  >
  > class MembershipSelectView(ListView):
  >    model = Membership
  >    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
  >        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
  >        current_membership = get_user_membership(self.request)
  >        context['current_membership'] = str(current_membership.membership)
  >        return context
  >
  >    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
  >        selected_membership_type = request.POST.get('membership_type')  
  >        user_membership = get_user_membership(request)
  >        user_subscription = get_user_subscription(request)      
  >        selected_membership_qs =Membership.objects.filter(
  >            membership_type = selected_membership_type) 
  >        if selected_membership_qs.exists():
  >            selected_membership = selected_membership_qs.first()
  >
  >            #validation
  >
  >
  >        if user_membership.membership == selected_membership:
  >            if user_subscription != None:
  >                messages.info(request, "you already have this membership. your \
  >                    next payment is due {}".format('get this value from stripe'))
  >                return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
  >
  >
  >        request.session['selected_membership_type'] = selected_membership.membership_type       
  >        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('memberships:payment'))
  >
  > def PaymentView(request):
  >    user_membership = get_user_membership(request)
  >    selected_membership = get_selected_membership(request)
  >    publishKey = settings.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY
  >
  >    context = {
  >        'publishKey': publishKey,
  >        'selected_membership': selected_membership
  >    }
  >    return render(request, "memberships/membership_payment.html", context)
  > ```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.